# Git Local Changes History Location On Hard Drive

Tags: git

I am new to Git. I am using Git Extension and I want to ask that if I make some changes and commit it locally but do not push it yet. Where is my local history stored???
I have the directory where I cloned the repository from the server. Is that the location where my local commit history is stored or is it stored anywhere in C drive?

Answer (score 5):

Git stores all its internal data in the hidden folder `.git`. It is in the root of your project checkout.

Comment: Unless you push commits back to the original git repository, your local copy is the only place where they are.

Answer (score 3):

By default when a repository is cloned, the cloning creates a working directory where the default branch is checked out automaticllay.  In the root folder of this working directory is a hidden folder; `.git`.  The `.git` folder is your local copy of the repository and contains the everything.

To be more specific, within the `.git` folder there are a few folders of interest for this question.

For each local branch, there is file at the path `.git/refs/heads`.  For instance, if you have the default `master` branch, there will be a file at `.git/refs/heads/master`.  This file contains the commit number of the latest commit on that branch.

The data for the commits is stored in files in the `.git/objects` folder; within a folder of the first two digits of the commit hash and a file of the remaining digits of the hash.  For instance, in the repository I'm currently working on the `master` file contains the commit hash `a50eed54467b98094438a22ae52995901c9a7ac9`.  The data for that commit is located in the `.git/objects/a5/0eed54467b98094438a22ae52995901c9a7ac9` file.

So these files are usually fairly small in my repository since the data is just the compressed difference from the parent commit.  The data contained in that file is just what is changed in that commit -- not everything.

The commit the remote branch is at is stored in a different location.  The remote branches are in the folder `.git/refs/remotes/<remote name>/<branch name>` -- very similar to how the local branches are stored.  When  pushed, the local branch **in the remote repostory** is updated -- when a branch is fetched, the remote branch file in this folder is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You **local** git repository is stored in files in the `.git` directory of your repo.